# How to get the correct MAC address of Windows Server 2008 out of multiple MAC addresses?

Tags: mac-address

I want to know the unique MAC address of my Windows Server 2008 R2. When I used `getmac` command in command prompt I got a list of MAC addresses(6 count) under Primary Address header. Could you please help me get the correct one out of this 6?

[image]

Edited:

If I put `ipconfig /all` it's showing more information under Tunnel adapter. I know I need to select Physical Address under that Tunnel adapter for getting MAC address, but my doubt is there are 6 Tunnel adapter information available.

Screenshot:

[image]

My software teams wants to know the MAC address of the Server where they are going to install that particular software . So that I tried those commands (getmac, ipconfig /all) and saw lot of MAC addresses.

Comment: Sadly, questions about host configuration are off topic here. You can consider asking this on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a good list of physical addresses of all your interfaces using

> ipconfig /all

within a Windows environment.

Give you a good output that looks like so:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D0-9E-6F-F2-B9-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

It will do this for each interface.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: Yup! I tried this also. but it showing a lists like the one you shared. My question is which one i need to prefer if my software team asking me single MAC address?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more regarding "which one i need to prefer if my software team asking me single MAC address". Is your teaming software asking for a MAC? It should use it from one of the interfaces part of the team. What teaming software are you using?

Comment: Yes! you are correct. Company software they need to install in server. LCM is the name of the software.

Comment: edited my question little more.. see the screenshot also.

Comment: It won't be any of the isatap adaptors that are listed in your screenshot. Can you confirm that the interfaces you want to team are actually enabled? You could give the interfaces a name in Windows and do another "ipconfig /all" and look at the name, then take the MAC that you want to use.

Comment: +1 for the answer and command. I appreciate your valuable help. But i'm new to this one. Could you please tell it more deeply how to do " You could give the interfaces a name in Windows and do another "ipconfig /all" and look at the name, then take the MAC that you want to use"